# Determining initial voltage across a capacitor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance, voltage

This one has got me stumped. I have a graph of voltage vs time and a corresponding power vs time graph. Taking the integral of the power vs time graph gives me the work done on the capacitor. Now the question says, consider the work done to be 0 now. Find the initial voltage across the capacitor with capacitance of 2 micro Farad

Now I'm using the equation U = .5 * C * V^2 and hoping something clicks but it doesn't seem to be working and I have no idea what else to do. This is the equation for my voltage vs time graph (earlier one when the work wasn't 0):

```
V = 2t, 0<t<4 micro seconds
V = -0.5t + 10, 4<t<7 micro seconds
```

Using that in this problem yields the following, correct?

```
V = 2t + v0, 0<t<4 micro seconds where v0 is the unknown initial voltage
V = -0.5t + 10, 4<t<7 micro seconds
```

Then its a matter of splitting the work done into two piecewise integrals using these two piece wise functions, doing the integration and ending up with something that helps me solve for v0, right? I am just looking to see if this is the avenue I should be going down. Is there a better way? What solution do you guys get?

Thanks

Comment: When you use the word power do you mean power delivered by the source of the power delivered to the capacitor?  Like lots of things that store potential energy capacitors only store half the energy which is generated by the source.  If the energy delivered by the source is $QV$ where $Q$ is the charge and $V$ is the voltage the energy stored in the capacitor is $\frac 1 2 QV = \frac 1 2 CV^2$.